# How to make "image banner" 100% of viewport with no margins, and rest of page center

Tags: html, css, image, viewport, skeleton-css-boilerplate

My question is how to get a banner to be `100%` of the viewport whilst keeping everything else center.

Right now I am trying to experiment with the Skeleton framework for the use of its pre made `@media` solutions and grid system. I noticed because it is a 960 grid system I can't put a banner inside it which will go to `100%` of the viewport ( as its restricted to `960px` ).

I would like a solution which allows me to continue using the Skeleton framework and I can get a work around for a `100%` viewport banner like [this site](http://brettryanstudios.com/contact/) as an example.

If this is not possible then I will need guidance for the best method of pulling this off.

Comment: Hi Dsundy It is looking good in terms of being a large banner, but it is falling behind my content within the Skeleton "container" and it looks as if it is not following normal doc flow. So My banner is not resting between the main content below and the nav above it.

Comment: Do you have a place where I can look at it? Or a screenshot? It's hard to visualize what you are saying.

Comment: I actually just fixed it by closing the div right after the opening banner div instead of after the closing skeleton container div, Not sure why, but it fixed it :D I think the background-size: cover; property is what sorted my problem mainly :) Thank you.

Comment: No problem. If it is resolved you should mark correct answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, this is usually done with a wrapper within the banner.

### Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Example Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    background: url(/* Your image */) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: /* Whatever height */;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto; /* This is what centers it */
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 96%;
 }
```

So you would have individual wrappers within each section of content (header, main, footer, etc.).

To use it with Skeleton it would look something like this (after a very brief look at their documentation).

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="container"><!-- Your 960 grid -->
        <div class="six columns><!-- Or however much of your 960 you want it to take up-->
            <!-- Content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```